# How to efficiently generate random points in a difference of two disks?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Consider two disks: $S$ with radius $R_S$ and position $(x_S,y_S)$, and $M$ with radius $R_M$ and position $(x_M,y_M)$. Let's denote the difference between these two sets as

$$V=S\setminus M.$$

Now the problem is: given two uniformly distributed random numbers $a,b\in[0,1]$, assuming $V\ne\emptyset$, compose from them a uniformly distributed point $p=(x,y)\in V$.

The most obvious solution would be to generate a point $p_0=f(a,b)\in S$ (where $f$ is [simple to construct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5837572/673852)) and, if $p_0\in M$, then discard it, otherwise return $p_0$. But for large overlaps between $S$ and $M$ (e.g. solar eclipse just before totality, with $S$ being the Sun and $M$ the Moon) this strategy will be grossly inefficient due to high rejection rate.

A better approach is to find the thinnest annulus $A$ with outer radius being $R_S$ and inner radius just small enough to fit $V$ into $A$. If we sample only inside the annulus (which is a simple modification of sampling in a full disk), we'll drastically reduce the rejection rate.

But this is still not the best. I suppose there should be a simple way to generate random points in $V$ without rejection at all. But I can't seem to find a way. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

With rejection, a simple improvement might be the following: assume WLOG that $y_S=y_M$ , $x_S-R_S < x_M-R_M$, so that one has the zone depicted in the figure. Let $h$ be the height of the smallest containing rectangle, let $t= (x_M-R_M) - (x_S-R_S)>0$.

Then, first map the square to a rectangle $a' = a t$  , $b'=b h$ . In this way, we get uniform points inside the green rectangle. Then shift $a'$ to the right so that it gets inside the red circle (arrows). If the resulting point is outside the $V$, discard and retry.

[image]

It would be possible to do something similar without rejection, but it looks quite cumbersome. Now we would shift and scale $a'$, so that it always get into $V$. But then, $b'$ should have been remapped so that its probability density is not uniform but proportional to the lentgh of the corresponding horizontal segment inside $V$.